# Django not detecting Less file

Tags: python, django, less

I'm trying to use less in django but for some reason am getting 404 when trying to access that less file. I've other css and js files that are working properly. I've successfully installed `django-static-precompiler` and have put static_precompiler to INSTALLED_APPS. I've also added     `static_precompiler.finders.StaticPrecompilerFinder` under STATICFILES_FINDERS

I'm really confused between `STATIC_URL`, `STATIC_PRECOMPILER_ROOT`, `STATIC_ROOT`

I'm doing this in development environment.

## header.html

```
{% load less %}
<link href="{% static "m1/less/universal.less" %}" rel="stylesheet/less" media="screen">
```

## settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "uploads/"

MEDIA_URL = "uploads/"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_PRECOMPILER_ROOT = '/m1/static/m1/less'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'm1',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'south',
    'social.apps.django_app.default',
    'django.contrib.redirects',
    'static_precompiler',

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'static_precompiler.finders.StaticPrecompilerFinder',
)
```

Comment: The usage examples on https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-static-precompiler are very different...

Comment: `_ROOT` refers to something in your filesystem, `_URL` to a web address.

Answer (score 1):

All `_ROOT` directories are about filesystem, all `_URL` directories are web addresses, like henrikstroem mentioned in comments.

Each `_URL` directory must match it's equivalent `_ROOT` directory on http server side, for example in your web server is configured to serve all files from `/your/app/static/` on address `http://example.com/static/`, that means you shoud configure `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` like this:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/your/app/static/" # this path must be absolute
STATIC_URL = "/static/" # this url can be relative to your domain or can be full url to your static directiory
```

Remember, all `_ROOT` directories must be absolute. You also shouldn't hardcode full path, but better use os.path functions to let python build that path relative to your settings file.

By default `STATIC_PRECOMPILER_ROOT` will be equal to `STATIC_ROOT` and it's fine, because static precompiler will put all compiled files into subdirectory named `COMPILED` by default, so it won't collide with other static files that you have. Also remember that static precompiler won't serve that files by itself, so it's better to keep them with static files.

So try to remove `STATIC_PRECOMPILER_ROOT` from your settings and fix other paths as I described above.

Also in your header you should use:

```
{% load compile_static %}
```

So static precompiler can detect your file, compile it and put proper path to compiled file.